# How do I delete a word when the cursor is in the middle of the word?

Tags: vim

How do I delete a word when the cursor is somewhere in the middle of that word (neither at the end or beginning of a word) in Vim?

Comment: this is programming related how?

Comment: Who else would use vim?

Comment: @Adam -- a mathematician, a physicist, people writing papers in LaTeX on a unix system the old fashioned way.

Comment: @Adam Hope most of the programmers are using VIM

Comment: I would use the "d" command which accepts notion, so you can use "b"("B") and "e"("E").

Comment: I use LaTeX within Eclipse using TeXlipse...

Comment: @abubacker: Goes a long way if you provide an example of what you want. Like ..
before - `sometexthere`
after - `somehere`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found that "diw"  ( delete inner word ) is the straight forward way to delete a word!

Answer (score 75):

What you need is the following keystrokes in normal mode (after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>):

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>   (meaning: delete inner word)

*-or-*

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>   (meaning: delete a word)

The second command also deletes all spaces after the word, or all spaces before the word if there are no spaces after the word.

For more related commands:

```
:help diw
:help daw
```

Comment: Unlike diw, this solution also deletes all the spaces after the current word.

Comment: Agreed, `daw` is best for deleting a word (Delete All of Word). The `iw` motion is more suitable if you want to type another word in its place, using `ciw` (Change Inner Word).

Comment: @nelstrom thank you for `ciw`, didn't know about it.

Answer (score 9):

`bdw` should do it.

`b`ack to the beginning of the word, `d`elete to the next `w`ord

Comment: This looks very work around , I want to do this more specific than this

Comment: +1, this is the shortest answer I know of. If it's still too long, @abubacker, see `map` on how to assign to a single keystroke (http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_map_keys_in_vim).

Comment: I like this solution, except that it doesn't work when your cursor is already on the first character of a word, meaning you have to mentally adjust the command for this special situation.

Comment: I also don't like this because you can't use `.` to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

After entering normal mode (by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>)

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> 
will **delete** the word.

Answer (score 0):

Or just do "db" or "de".
e move cursor end of word, b move cursor beginning of word.

Comment: `de` would not delete whole word if the cursor is not at the first character. `db` would never delete whole word because it doesn't delete the character under the cursor. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14806106/3162368) and answers.