# In VIM, why doesn't `db` delete the character under the cursor?

Tags: vim

I read that <kbd>b</kbd> is like the reverse of <kbd>e</kbd> i.e. <kbd>b</kbd> does what e does but backwards.

So if I hit <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> on a word and the cursor is on the first letter of the word, it deletes the whole word.  That's great!

But if I hit <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> on a word and the cursor is on the last letter of the word, it deletes the whole word except for the letter that the cursor was on!

I know I could just move over one character when using <kbd>b</kbd> but I would like to keep things consistent.  And perhaps someone could enlighten me as to why <kbd>b</kbd> behaves like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the vim cursor is a pretty disgusting thing and poorly designed, to mimic the block cursor of terminals. the cursor position is actually at the start / left hand side of the block, so if the block is "on" `k` in `bark` and you <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> you're actually deleting from `r` to `b`.

fortunately, [you can change the cursor](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor) to something reasonable

Comment: I would also like to apologize for how bad that vim wiki page is, but all vim wiki pages are just as bad.

Comment: literally nothing in vim is intuitive. it's all steep learning.

Comment: No, it's learning the basics right. Intuition comes after knowledge. An interesting case of un-intuitiveness is `cw`/`ce`.

Comment: What about the cursor are you suggesting changing? Somehow I don’t think changing the cursor color or blink in anyway helps understand what is going on. Further, it’s not really meant to “mimic” the block cursor of a terminal, it often *is* the block cursor of the terminal. Not everyone uses gVim.

Comment: Changing cursor from block to a line so the line is where the cursor actually is.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the entire word backwards?

Comment: When you keep cursor at the last character of the line you can't move it right anymore. So i don't think that cursor is poorly designed, it serves it purpose well. I think that "inclusive" and "exclusive" explanation fits much better https://stackoverflow.com/a/14806156/7284582

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>b</kbd> is not the opposite of <kbd>e</kbd>, as <kbd>b</kbd> is an *exclusive motion*, while <kbd>e</kbd> is *inclusive*. From `:help e` & `:help b`:

> **`e`** Forward to the end of word `[count]` *inclusive*. Does not stop in an empty line.
>
> **`b`** `[count]` words backward.  *exclusive* motion.

And from `:help exclusive`:

> A character motion is either inclusive or exclusive.  When inclusive,
>   the start and end position of the motion are included in the
>   operation.  When exclusive, the last character towards the end of the
>   buffer is not included. Linewise motions always include the start and
>   end position.

Comment: @WMR No, `ge` moves backwards to the end of a word.

Answer (score 6):

You should have a look at `:help text-objects` : it allows you to apply commands to *smart* objects, like words, sentences, or paragraphs.

For erasing a word, no matter the position of the cursor, you should use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

Comment: what if you want to delete 5 words backwards and you now stand on the last letter of the fifth word? How do you usually do this?

Comment: @ayrat : you could use `d5b` to move over five words backwords, but it seems the character under the cursor is still there. An alternative is to use something like `dFx` to delete backwards until character 'x'.

Comment: `dFx` also leaves the character under cursor unremoved. thanks anyway!

Comment: @Aryat `dFxx` works fine if you want the character under cursor removed.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using `v` to use the visual mode in backward motion.

```
" Backward motion, inclusive the current cursor.
onoremap b vb
onoremap F vF
onoremap T vT
```

This is working as intended and good enough for my typical uses. Related article:
https://jdhao.github.io/2019/05/18/nvim_exclusive_inclusive_motion/

Answer (score 0):

Delete A Word <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

Deletes the word under your cursor and the space to the left leaving the cursor at the end of the previous word. This is a repeatable change. In VIM you can repeat with <kbd>.</kbd>

---

<kbd>$</kbd>       |    Then there was non <kbd>e</kbd>

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> | Then there wa<kbd>s</kbd>

<kbd>.</kbd>   |  Then ther<kbd>e</kbd>