# Making backwards motions always inclusive?

Tags: vim

Background about exclusive motions for those who need:

I've always been annoyed by how motions work in Vim after an operator. Recently I heard this is because of them usually being "exclusive": they leave out the rightmost character as opposed to "inclusive" operations which would pick up everything under the cursor between start and end points. For some reason almost all motions in operator pending mode seem to work this way, for instance pressing "dl" will only delete the character under the cursor (leaving the rightmost second character out), d0 at the end of a line will leave the last character on the line unaffected. Some motions like "d$" or "de" then again break this pattern and also include the rightmost character. More at [Motion.txt](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#operator).

I find the concept of exclusivity unnecessary and confusing. I can understand that when you are "searching" for the next occurrence of a word, a mark or a search result, you'll usually want to leave the actual target of the motion unselected when operating. Exclusive motions achieve this. But the inconsistency of the exclusivity concept is weird. Main problem is when you move somewhere backwards: the operation will leave the rightmost character, the starting character, untouched, and still will operate on the target of your movement no matter what you do, unlike when searching forwards. For example, you'd expect "edb" to delete a word completely, but it doesn't. Meanwhile "bde" does. "dl" deletes only the character under cursor (instead of including also the one to the right) and "dh" only one character on the left. [This inconsistency is annoying, and seemingly makes it look like Vim secretly is keeping the cursor actually between letters on the left side of the cursor block.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806106/in-vim-why-doesnt-db-delete-the-character-under-the-cursor)

Luckily, using "v" after the operator toggles exclusivity for characterwise operations, so I've been able to fix some motions such as b and h with onoremap vb. But it's only a partial solution; Many "searching" movement commands may move either backwards or forwards, so making them include the rightmost character when moving backwards is impossible without making forward movement undesirably affect the first character of the target of motion.

*My question in short*: Is there any simple way to make all operations work inclusively (as to include the character under the starting point of the cursor) when moving backwards relative to cursor position, without affecting forward motion?

(Even better would be entirely forgetting the whole exclusivity thing and having "v" toggle whether to include the target of the motion (so "dn" would delete from cursor till the start of the search result, "dvn" would delete from cursor to the end of the result), but that would probably mean editing the source.)

Sorry for long post, it was hard to explain and I'm annoyed.

Comment: This is likely tied to the way `vim` (and other programs) think about cursor/insert position - even though the cursor may display on top of a specific character, the current insert position is between the highlighted character and the previous one, in which case "delete from beginning of line to here" will not touch the highlighted character, but "delete from here to end of line" would... In other words, it was probably a conscious design decision to work the way it does...

Comment: @twalberg; Oh man. Seems like there's no way around it then if Vim really "sees" the cursor being between characters. Guess I'll have to consider switching normal mode cursor to a thick bar then. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 2):

In most scenarios described by you, vim *text-objects* would certainly be better candidates to use rather than motions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues with in/exclusivity.  Things don't seem intuitive to me yet.  I don't use search motions much (e.g. d/ or d?), but found something very helpful in `:h search-offset`.

A motion like `v/hello/e` will go through the end of the search term, rather than
stop at the beginning.  Similarly `v?hello?e` will stop at the end of a search term,
rather than go to the beginning.

If I understand you correctly, these motions might do what you're looking for:

- `d/likes<cr>` -- delete up to but not including the search result
- `dv?likes<cr>` -- delete back to and through the previous search result
- `d/likes/e<cr>` -- delete up to and including the search result
- `d?likes?e1<cr>` -- delete back to but not including the previous search result

So, to answer your question (the even better part), you could use `d/hello/e` to delete through 'hello', then `dn` to delete through the next.  It'd only work well going one direction though.  You'd have to re-setup the search to go the other direction, in this case `dv?hello`, then `dn`.

---

Here's how I started to understand these commands.  It hurts my brain.  Also, for other people reading this answer, I included explanation of in/exclusive behavior and the `v` operator  (`:h exclusive` and `:h o_v`).

(Take `^---^` to be the visual range, and the characters between the `|`s
as the characters the `/` and `?` will operate on)

#### One

When we search `likes` from the beginning of the line, we get the visual region

```
John likes walking
^----^
```

We kind of want whatever operation we do to operate on the letters between `|`s

```
|John |likes walking
 ^-----^
```

That way, `d<motion>` won't delete the first `l` in likes.

This is the behavior vim defaults to.

#### Two

When we search `likes` from the end of the line, we get the visual region

```
John likes walking
     ^-----------^
```

We kind of want whatever operation we do to operate on the letters between `|`s

```
John |likes walking|
      ^-----------^
```

That way, `d<motion>` deletes the whole region between the end of the line and the
beginning of the search.

Because vim defaults to the convenient behavior for forward motion in **One**, the letters that will be operated on are actually

```
John |likes walkin|g
      ^------------^
```

Notice this is consistent with the first behavior - excluding the last character
of the highlighted region.  (Note: this is what vim docs mean when they say the `/` and `?`
motion are *exclusive* motions).

We can change this by using `dv<motion`.  By using `dv<motion>`, the letters operated on will be

```
John |likes walking|
      ^-----------^
```

Great, problem solved.

#### What we have so far

- `d/likes<cr>` -- delete up to but not including the search result
- `dv?likes<cr>` -- delete back to and through the previous search result

Ok, now how do we get the others?

- `???` -- delete up to and including the search result
- `???` -- delete back to but not including the previous search result

A search offset `e` will do it (`:h search-offset`). It's great,
but it's confusing reason about, at least to me.  We'll see why below.

#### Three

When we search `likes/e` from the beginning of the line (`v/likes/e`), we get the visual region

```
John likes walking
^--------^
```

We want whatever operation we do to operate on the letters between `|`s

```
|John likes| walking
 ^--------^
```

That way, `d<motion>` will delete the last `s` in `likes`

This is the behavior vim defaults to.  But note!  Now it's *including* the last
letter in the visual region.  Vim automatically changes the behavior of the `/` motion
to be *inclusive* when the `e` search offset is used

#### Four

When we search `likes?e` from the end of the line (`v?likes?e`), we get the visual region

```
John likes walking
         ^-------^
```

We want whatever operation we do to operate on the letters between `|`s

```
John likes| walking|
         ^--------^
```

That way, `d<motion>` deletes the whole region between the end of the line and excluding
the search result.

Because vim defaults to the convenient behavior for forward motion in **Three**, the letters that will be operated on are actually

```
John like|s walking|
          ^-------^
```

This is even weirder.  Because vim's default behavior is now *inclusive* with the `e` search-offset,
the final `g` in walking is included be default.  No `dv` needed to include it.

We can modify it by using `d?likes?e1`.  The `1` means "go one character to the right of the end of
the search result".  This will give

```
John likes| walking|
         ^--------^
```

Ok, that's what we're looking for.